# inside xcframework , the ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst is dedicated to arm or intel processor?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcframework

inside an xcframework we have the subfolder :

- ios-arm64
- ios-arm64_x86_64-maccatalyst
- ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
- macos-arm64_x86_64
- tvos-arm64
- tvos-arm64_x86_64-simulator

can someone tell me for with exact processor they are made? I understand that `ios-arm64` is for all iOS running on ARM processor, but what for is `ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator`? for an arm processor (arm64) or for an intel (x86) processor ?

Answer (score 0):

> ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator

is for both. The binary contains the compilable code for running that xcframework on an simulator for which Xcode runs on an Mac machine with Intel architecture (Intel x64) or for a Mac machine running Arm architecture (M1 Pro/Max/Ultra or M2)

in general the portion *arm64_x86_64* indicates that the binary in that subfolder can be compiled on both the architectures

you can also check the terminal command “lipo”, which can tell what architecture a given binary contains